# Conflicting use of babel/register

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I'm having what appears to be a conflict in `babel/register` between two local npm packages.

In a package I am doing the following:

```
require('babel/register');
require('index');
```

And in the index file of the same package:

```
require('test');
```

And in the "test" package:

```
require('babel/register');
require('test/index');
```

This throws the following error:

`throw new Error("only one instance of babel/polyfill is allowed");`

But if I take the `babel/register` line out of the "test" package, I get the following error in the `index` file of the "test" package:

```
import fs from 'fs';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

I have tried using `System.import` to import the "test" package as well (using the polyfill specified on the BabelJS site), but in this context, I get the same error as above. How should I go about importing one package into the other and preserve the ability to use ES6 imports/exports and other ES6 features?

EDIT: I've simplified this a little, I am still requiring the "test" into to the first package, but I am not loading an intermediary file. Instead, the "main" file of "test is set to `test/index.` Theoretically, now it is just loading a single ES6 module, which it should be able to register. I still get the above error.

Comment: Generally the expectation is that libraries will be pre-compiled before distribution. `babel/register` doesn't process files inside `node_modules` by default.

Comment: It does if you follow the pattern I'm following. If I completely exclude the second package, all of the modules in the first package are registered and transformed.

Comment: I'm confused. Your question says if you take `babel/register` out of the `test` module, it gives an error about the import. That's because `test` is in `node_modules` so it won't be compiled. Are you expecting the outer `babel/register` to also compile `test`?

Comment: Yes, "test" lives in `node_modules`, but why shouldn't `babel/register` transform it? Shouldn't `babel/register` just compile any ES6 module you try to load?

Comment: That's what I said in my first comment. `babel/register` by default only processes things directly inside your module, not inside `node_modules`, unless you explicitly tell it what to process. Loading would be way slower if it just tried to transpile every file you reference. Plus not all files are valid ES6 modules. [See the Note:](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/#usage).

Comment: Ah, I see now, thanks. Do you have a suggestion as to how I should go about importing the second package?

Comment: How is `test` distributed? Generally the expectation is that modules will be distributed as precompiled ES5. If you really want to compile it after though, you can change the `ignore` and/or `only` regex just like link I posted shows.

Comment: You should make this into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: met the same problem, did you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have seen, `babel/register` is only meant to be run once per application, and generally that would be the top-level application that you are starting.

The issue you are facing is that by default, `require('babel/register')` will only set up your system to transpile files directly inside the module, it will not process `node_modules`. The expectation generally that anything in `node_modules` will have been compiled ahead of time when published to your module registry.

One option is to pass `ignore: false` as an option, e.g. `require('babel/register')({ignore: false});` however this is generally a bad idea and can lead to other problems. That will make Babel transpile *all* files, but that is not always a safe things to do because not all JavaScript code is guaranteed to be a valid ES6 module.

The best solution would be to transpile your `test` module ahead of time. If that isn't going to work however, you can use the `only` option to specify a regex or glob for the paths that should be transpiled.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got away with setting:

```js
self._babelPolyfill = false;
```

I don't know if setting the polyfill a second time will cause some subtle problems, but with a good number of unit tests, I didn't see any problems by using this hack to avoid the script choking.

Answer (score 0):

The error: `only one instance of babel/polyfill is allowed` is exactly what @loganfsmyth mentioned: Multiple polyfills, which can be caused by using both `babel-node` and requiring `./register-babel`, at the same time.

However, in my case, this error was strangely not showing up *until* I had another error. I mean, everything was working, then I had an `EADDRINUSE` error. When it happened, it got shadowed and the polyfill error showed up. Very strange. I haven't touched my code in anywhere related to Babel.

Once I fixed the polyfill, the `EADDRINUSE` showed up and I was able to solve everything.